# Problemas para conectar con base de datos de SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
public static int Guardar(string codigo, string nombre, string apellido)
{
    Clase_Conexion conexion = new Clase_Conexion();

    int retorno = 0;//existe codigo. Producto repetido
    String sql="INSERT into Table (codigo, nombre, apellido) VALUES (@codigo, @nombre, @apellido)";
    //String cstring = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["conecta"].ConnectionString;
    //using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(cstring))
    //{
        using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand())
        {
            command.Connection = conexion.con;            // <== lacking
            command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            command.CommandText = "INSERT into Table (codigo, nombre, apellido) VALUES (@codigo, @nombre, @apellido)";
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@codigo", codigo);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nombre", nombre);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@apellido", apellido);

            try
            {
                conexion.conectar();
                int recordsAffected = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                retorno = 1;
            }
            catch (SqlException)
            {
                // error here
            }
            finally
            {
                conexion.cerrar();
            }
        }
    //}
    return retorno;
}
```

Y tengo la siguiente clase de conexión:

```
public class Clase_Conexion
{
    public SqlConnection con;
    public void conectar()
    {           
        con = new SqlConnection("data source = localhost; initial catalog = BD_ejemplo"); // LOCALHOST
        con.Open();
    }
    //metodo para cerrar
    public void cerrar()
    {
        con.Close();
    }
}
```

Tengo una base de datos llamada **`BD_ejemplo.mdf`** en **`App_Data`**

Y en al web.config tengo la siguiente `conectionString` de la siguiente forma:

```
 <add name="conecta" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=aspnet-ejemplo_ajax_webform-20170317135041;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-ejemplo_ajax_webform-20170317135041.mdf" />
```

Primeramente estaba usando la conexión mediante el web.config, pero no me resultó, ya que decía que no encontraba la ruta de la base de datos. Posteriormente decidí hacerlo mediante una clase de conexión, pero tampoco puedo, ya que me sale el siguiente error:

> Error relacionado con la red o específico de la instancia mientras se establecía una conexión con el servidor SQL Server. No se encontró el servidor o éste no estaba accesible. Compruebe que el nombre de la instancia es correcto y que SQL Server está configurado para admitir conexiones remotas. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - No se pudo abrir una conexión con SQL Server)

Quisiera saber cómo hago la conexión tanto por el web.config y en especial con el archivo de conexión (clase). Sé que algo está mal escrito, o algún parámetro me falta ingresar en:

```
con = new SqlConnection("data source = localhost; initial catalog = BD_ejemplo") //(para el caso de la clase de conexion)
```

Espero poder encontrar la solución.

Observacion: Por ahora estoy sin contraseña a la base de datos. Ya que agregue desde el mismo Visual Studio.

---

He comprobado la conección y esta correcto. Aquí muestro los siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El nombre del archivo de la base de datos es visual studio 2013\Projects\ejemplo_ajax_webform\ejemplo_ajax_webform\App_Data\BD_ejemplo.dmdf

Y en Advance, hay una parte que dice :

Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename="C:\Users\Usuario_X\Documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\ejemplo_ajax_webform\ejemplo_ajax_webform\App_Data\BD_ejemplo.dmdf.mdf";Integrated Security=True

___EDICION 2:___________________
He probado de esta otra forma:

he creado una clase coneccion:

```
public class Conexion
{
    public SqlCommand cmd;
    public SqlConnection Conn;
    public string Conexion_uno= "Data Source=localhost;" +
        "Initial Catalog=BD_ejemplo;" +
        "Integrated Security=SSPI;";// { get; set; }        

    public void Abrir_Conexion()
    {
        try
        {
            this.cmd = new SqlCommand();
            this.Conn = new SqlConnection();
            this.Conn.ConnectionString = Conexion_uno;
            this.Conn.Open();

            this.cmd.CommandTimeout = 10000;
            this.cmd.Connection = Conn;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message.ToString().Trim());
            CerrarConexion();
        }
    }
    public void CerrarConexion()
    {
        Conn.Close();
    }
}
```

Y en el metodo guardar pruebo así:

```
 public static int Guardar(int codigo, string nombre, string apellido)
    {
        Conexion conexion = new Conexion();

        int retorno = 0;//existe codigo. Producto repetido
        //String cstring = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString;
        //using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(cstring))
        //{
            using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand())
            {
                command.Connection = conexion.Conn;            // <== lacking
                //command.Connection = connection;            // <== lacking
                command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Usuario(codigo, nombre, apellido) VALUES(@codigo, @nombre, @apellido)";
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@codigo", codigo);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nombre", nombre);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@apellido", apellido);
                //command.Parameters.Add("@codigo", SqlDbType.Int).value = codigo  
                //command.Parameters.Add("@nombre", SqlDbType.Varchar, 50).value = nombre;
                //command.Parameters.Add("@apellido", SqlDbType.Varchar, 50).value = apellido;

                try
                {
                    conexion.Abrir_Conexion();
                    //connection.Open();
                    int recordsAffected = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    retorno = 1;
                }
                catch (SqlException)
                {
                    // error here
                }
                finally
                {
                    //connection.Close();
                    conexion.CerrarConexion();
                }
            //}
        }
        return retorno;

    }
```

pero me dice el siguiente error:

**ExecuteNonQuery: la propiedad Connection no se ha inicializado.**

Answer (score 0):

Le recomiendo que verifique lo obvio:
Lo primero que te sugiero es que hagas la conexión desde el visual studio por el explorador de servidores y lo copies y pegues en le WebConfig, obviamente luego de confirmar la conexión.

También Verifica que el servicio si se este ejecutando. 
Verifica que no sea un problema con el firewall ( puerto 1433).

La mayoría de las veces que me presenta ese error es un error en la cadena de conexion en el webconfig.

Comment: Hola @Software lover, edite la pregunta detallando la verificación de que se puede conectar con una imagen. Y coloque mas información Data Source que tiene en Advance(segun la imagen). Mi pregunta es: ¿que debería copiar y pegar en la webconfig?

Comment: Yo lo hago así: En el explorador de servidores realizo la conexión, cuando la pruebo y obtengo un resultado exitoso, le doy clic derecho y selecciono la opción "Propiedades" , selecciono y copio la cadena de conexión, voy al webconfig, en la sección  de conectionString pego la cadena de conexion, copiada para reemplazar la existente que esta entre comillas dobles.

Comment: Gracias @Software lover, he podido conectarme y hacer funcionar el ingreso de datos mediante la webconfig, colocando lo siguiente:
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\Usuario_x\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\ejemplo_ajax_webform\ejemplo_ajax_webform\App_Data\BD_ejemplo.mdf;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
  </connectionStrings>
pero no puedo aun probar para hacer mediante un archivo de clase

Comment: Con estas lineas puedes obtener la cadena de conexion desde una clase      //Obtenemos la cadena de conexión de App.config o Web.config llamandola por su nombre:

string cadenaConexion = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString;

Answer (score 0):

Mira yo te recomiendo mejor este método, me ha sacado de apuros. Crea un método en una clase llamada "Conexion" y agrega esto:

```
public class clsConexioncs
{

    private SqlCommand cmd;
    private SqlConnection Conn;
    public string Conexion;// { get; set; }        

    public void AbrirConexion()
    {
        try
        {
            this.cmd = new SqlCommand();                                                                   
            this.Conn = new SqlConnection();
            this.Conn.ConnectionString = Conexion;
            this.Conn.Open();

                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             this.cmd.CommandTimeout = 10000;
            this.cmd.Connection = Conn;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message.ToString().Trim());
            CerrarConexion();
        }
    }
}
```

Dentro del webConfig, agrega esto:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-Dash_Femsa-20170215043808.mdf;Initial Catalog=aspnet-Dash_Femsa-20170215043808;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
    <add name="DefaultDW" connectionString="Data Source=10.12.14.6;Initial Catalog=PRM; User ID= CorrelatorUser; Password= CorrelatorUser01" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
  </connectionStrings>
```

Solo configuralo con tus variables y veras que te funciona, es mas seguro y concreto.

Mandala a llamar desde tu main y veras que te sirve para todo tu programa.

Comment: Hola @Ric_hc , consulta, como lo haría en el metodo Guardar, ya que lo intente agregando String cstring = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString;
pero quede igual, como es que se asocia la webconfig con la clase coneccion y en el metodo guardar, ¿podría hacer un ejemplo, colocar el mismo metodo guardar que puse editado según lo sugerido?

Comment: ¿Guardar?, perdon, disculpame, no entiendo tu pregunta.

Comment: en el metodo public static int Guardar(string codigo, string nombre, string apellido)
{ ....
es donde estoy tratando de insertar unos datos a la base de datos, pero como hay problemas de coneccion con la base, surgió mi pregunta

Comment: Agrega tu código para que podamos revisar y te podamos ayudar

Comment: pero si está está agregado, es el primer codigo que puse en la pregunta

Comment: ok, he actualizado la respuesta, crea una clase como te la muestro y agrega el código.

Comment: Hola @Ric_hc, he editado mi pregunta, y lo he hecho tal como me lo sugeriste, pero me da error. En la misma pregunta detalle el codigo y el error que me da. Estoy casi seguro que el error es la variable Conexion_uno, que es la que le paso al ConnectionString, pero no se que parametros o como debo describir la variable que se le pasa al ConnectionString. Yo lo tengo asi: Conexion_uno= "Data Source=localhost;" +
            "Initial Catalog=BD_ejemplo;" +
            "Integrated Security=SSPI;"
BD_ejemplo es un archivo .mdf

Comment: Bien, ya lo solucione, antes del sqlcommand debo poner conexion.conectar();